# IBM MQ is not closing application connections

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

Following the guidelines of dotnet client usage from the IBM MQ client samples, I have the following code to close the Queue and the Queue Manager:

```
public void DisconnectMQQueue()
    {
        if (MQQueue!= null)
        {
            MQQueue.Close();
        }
    }

    public void DisconnectMQQueueManager()
    {
        if (MQQueueManager != null)
        {
            MQQueueManager.Disconnect();
        }
    }

    MQConnection.DisconnectMQQueue();
    MQConnection.DisconnectMQQueueManager();
```

However in MQ explorer, I see the application connections constantly increase. And once it reaches max, I get the MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE error. Is there any I am missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Please let us know the version of MQ Client you are using. The code snippet you have shown uses MQQueue and MQQueueManager as variables and  Close and Disconnect is being called on them. But MQQueue and MQQueueManager are actually class names in MQ .NET Client, the program may not have compiled. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I've created an object which encapsulates MQ .NET Client. It is called MQConnection. And those two methods are belong to that object. They called when MQConnection gets disposed. Version I am using is 7.5.0.1

Comment: As per suggestion below from Hogan & co this question has been marked as duplicate. Can you post a new question? But my question still remains: it's not possible to use variable with name MQQueue and MQQueueManager. Application will simply not compile. In your new question can you post more of MQConnection class. I would recommend adding a MQQueueManager=null immediately after calling Disconnect.